# View credit card transactions

Tags: api, credit-card, finance, credit-card-track-data

I want to build an application that tracks frequented vendors that a user visits, and makes credit card charges to.

Are there any APIs/services out there that allow for the tracking of user credit card transactions (that have obviously been approved by said user)?

USE CASE:

A user signs up for an account and adds their credit card information. Charges made with that credit card would then be stored in my constructed system.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I don't know how to make the question anymore specific. I am not asking for steps or source code to do this, just if anything exists, and if there is anywhere I can go to research more. Not sure if this is the appropriate forum to ask, but figured I would try. I've tried adding a little more context...